# new Date(2020, 12, 122) should throw me error

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date(2020, 12, 122);
return
Sun May 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

but actually it is wrong because 122 day does not exist.

How can I return wrong date format instead of recalculated date? Is even possible in javascript to get date error if is invalid?

Also `new Date(2020, 02, 29);` should not be valid

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date  Doesn't look like there is a strict version.  If you give it more days than are in the month it most likely just rolls over into the next month/year

Comment: Month 12 doesn't exist either, as it's zero indexed ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could make a "safe" constructor that checks to make sure the month and year remained the same:

```js
function safeConstructDate(year, month, date) {
    const d = new Date(year, month, date);
    if (d.getMonth() !== month || d.getFullYear() !== year) {
        throw new RangeError("Date overflow.");
    }
    return d;
}

const d = safeConstructDate(2020, 11, 122);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a quirk of JS Date. It takes number of days, and adds them to the date, in your case it took 122 days as 2020-12-01 + 121 days = 2021-05-02

```js
const d = new Date(2020, 12, 122);

console.log("Dec 2020 with 122 days", d)

const valid = new Date(2020, 12, 1);

console.log("Dec 2020 with 1 day", valid)

const addDays = (date, days) => {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

console.log("Dec 2020 with 1 day + 121 days", addDays(valid, 121));
```